# How to use OpenHashSet in my application program in Spark?

Tags: scala, hadoop, hashmap, apache-spark, hashset

I know OpenHashSet is private in spark ,according to the private[spark],but usually we need a faster HashMap or HashSet implementation when the data is really big.How can I use these data structures in my own code?Or are there other alternatives?Thanks!

Comment: Normally, one would use an RDD (which under the hood might use OpenHashSet etc) so that your data and processing are distributed. Can you explain your use case for using a HashSet/HashMap directly?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it is open source, so you could fork/copy it, rename the package to avoid conflicts, and remove the `private[spark]` restriction. But of course this depends on you specific use case as Paul mentions.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7569978/forking-an-apache-license-v2-open-source-project-and-copyright-notices) for legal issues.